# Prevent duplicated entries in blog.js with Gatsby when modifying theme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm developing a landing page with Gatsby and it includes a blog. I've made some components to achieve the expected design but when I map the data of the entries (in `blog.js`) it shows the components as the same number of entries (if there are 2 entries the components renders 2 times), like this (`aaaa` and `eee` are two different entries):

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

This is my code in blog.js:

```
class Blog extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props
    const siteTitle = data.site.siteMetadata.title
    const posts = data.allMdx.edges

    return (
      <Layout location={this.props.location} title={siteTitle}>
        <SEO title="Blog" />
        <div style={{ margin: "52px", marginTop: "120px" }}>
          {posts.map(({ node }) => {
            const title = node.frontmatter.title || node.fields.slug
            const author = node.frontmatter.author
            return (
              <div>
                <CardBlog
                  title={title}
                  author={author}
                  publicationDate={node.frontmatter.date}
                  description={node.frontmatter.description}
                />
              </div>
            )
          })}
           {posts.map(({ node }) => {
            const title = node.frontmatter.title || node.fields.slug
            return (
              <div key={node.fields.slug}>
                <h3
                  style={{
                    marginBottom: rhythm(1 / 4),
                  }}
                >
                  <Link
                    style={{ boxShadow: `none` }}
                    to={`blog${node.fields.slug}`}
                  >
                    {title}
                  </Link>
                </h3>
                <small>{node.frontmatter.date}</small>
                <p
                  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: node.frontmatter.description || node.excerpt,
                  }}
                />
              </div>
            )
          })}
        </div>
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}

export default Blog;

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }
    allMdx(sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }) {
      edges {
        node {
          excerpt
          fields {
            slug
          }
          frontmatter {
            date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
            title
            description
            author
            position
            image
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

CardBlog is the component where I do all the structure to have the post ordered like that, and just pass the props of the data I want to display. How can I prevent these multiple entries? Am I mapping the wrong way?

My gatsby-node.js file:

```
const path = require(`path`)
const { createFilePath } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)

exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
const { createPage } = actions

const blogPost = path.resolve(`./src/templates/blog-post.js`)
return graphql(
`
  {
    allMdx(
      sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }
      limit: 1000
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          fields {
            slug
          }
          frontmatter {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
 ).then(result => {
if (result.errors) {
  throw result.errors
}

// Create blog posts pages.
const posts = result.data.allMdx.edges

posts.forEach((post, index) => {
  const previous = index === posts.length - 1 ? null : posts[index + 1].node
  const next = index === 0 ? null : posts[index - 1].node

  createPage({
    path: `blog${post.node.fields.slug}`,
    component: blogPost,
    context: {
      slug: post.node.fields.slug,
      previous,
      next,
    },
  })
})

return null
 })
   }

   exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
   const { createNodeField } = actions

   if (node.internal.type === `Mdx`) {
const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode })
createNodeField({
  name: `slug`,
  node,
  value,
})
   }
   }
```

Comment: Your mapping is fine, you're probably creating duplicated nodes from your Markdown files. Can you also share your `gatsby-node.js` (or, better, a reproduction repo)?

Comment: @RobinMétral i added my gatsby-node.js in the body of the question, since is a landing for a company's product im not sure im able to share it :(